# How to strip path while archiving with TAR

Tags: linux, unix, archive, tar

I have a file that contain list of files I want to archive with tar.
Let's call it `mylist.txt`

It contains:

```
/path1/path2/file1.txt
/path1/path2/file3.txt
...
/path1/path2/file10.txt
```

What I want to do is to archive this file into a tarball but excluding `/path1/path2/`.
Currently by doing this:

```
tar -cvf allfiles.tar -T mylist.txt
```

preserves the path after unarchiving.

I tried this but won't work too:

```
tar -cvf -C /path1/path2 allfiles.tar -T mylist.txt
```

It archives all the files in `/path1/path2` even those which are not in mylist.txt

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: are all files in the same path?

Comment: @hovanessyan: yes all in same path.

Comment: same path == same directory ? why not `cd` to that directory and invoke tar there?

Comment: This question and answer are correct and amazing, even if this question is closed.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is now closed, but the following might do what you want: `tar -cf allfiles.tar -T mylist.txt --transform 's|path1/path2/||'`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your "Extraction phase" you can use the `strip-components` flag like

```
tar xvf tarname.tar --strip-components=n
```

which will remove the first n leading components of the file name. Although if you have different file-path-components this will not work for all cases.

If you want to do it while archiving, only one thing comes to mind, and I will share

INPUT: list of files + full paths

1) for each line, split the path out of the filename

2) execute cd to that path and tar on that filename

3) repeat for each line

Comment: thanks. I'm aware of `strip-components`. However still prefer stripping while archiving.

Comment: The "cd & tar, then cd & tar" sounds a lot like the examples in [the tar manual on "Changing the Working Directory" at gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/directory.html) using -C in the "middle" of a command line to cd & add following files from that dir, with multiple -C & more files, all added to the "root" of the tar. Can even put `-C/path` lines in `--files-from` file lists

Comment: @Xen2050 Nailed this on the head.  `tar -cf output.tar -C /path/to target_directory` did what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: note, the `-C` parameter does not work if you're attempting to specify a wildcard. If you have a bunch of images in `/home/me/images` and you try `tar -czf mypictures.tar.gz -C /home/me/images *.jpg` it will fail (shell expansion expands the wildcard before the tar command is run, so it populates with any .jpg files in the current directory).