# While creating the tar file the entire path is created as the tar file

Tags: linux, shell, sh, tar

Hi I have created a shell script to backup the content from a directory. Its creating the file but its preserving the entire path.

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/sh

#creating the destination file
dest="../Demo_Projects/backup/"

#the file name to be created
fname=ug-$(date +%-Y%-m%-d)-$(date +%-T).tgz

#executing the script
tar -cPf $dest$fname "../Demo_Projects/JsonP/"
```

This creates the tar file but the entire path is retained in the tar file.
Is there a way where we can just have the innermost directory.

I know this question is previously been answered
[tar file preserves full path. how to stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532651/tar-file-preserves-full-path-how-to-stop-it)

But when I followed the answer - my modified code is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh

#creating the destination file
dest="../Demo_Projects/backup/"

#the file name to be created
fname=ug-$(date +%-Y%-m%-d)-$(date +%-T).tgz

#executing the script
exec('cd /home/abhishek/Demo_Projects/ && tar -cPf $dest$fname /JsonP/')
```

but this results in a run time error

```
abhishek@pk:~/sh$ ./backup_demo.sh
./backup_demo.sh: 11: ./backup_demo.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I am new to shell scripting and any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You linked to a question regarding PHP, not shell.

Comment: ohh.. my mistake. Late nights are killing me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
#executing the script
exec('cd /home/abhishek/Demo_Projects/ && tar -cPf $dest$fname /JsonP/')
```

Should be

```
#executing the script
cd /home/abhishek/Demo_Projects/ && tar -cPf $dest$fname /JsonP/
```

Comment: And can I make a back up of the var/www/ directory using the above script?

I asked this question coz throwing the error "Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now" and the folder it cannot open is the destination folder. When I gave echo of $dest and $fname, its wasnt empty. and I have created a symlink of the var dir on the home dir. Thanks