# Tar files from different directories without paths

Tags: bash, shell, archive, tar

```
I have a following structure:

-folder1
   -folder2
     -file1
     -file2
   -folder3
     -folder4
       -folder5
         -file3
         -file4
```

Using bash I need to create a .tar archive **in the actual directory**, which will contain 4 files(file1,file2,file3,file4). Everything that I've tried makes an archive of files with their paths. What I need is an archive of *just files*, which must contain:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

Comment: Have you tried --strip-components=n or --strip=n (used when extracting), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043579/how-to-strip-path-while-archiving-with-tar?

Comment: @user2672165 No, because I don't need to extract it, just to create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the filenames and their directories you can use the `-C`/`--directory` option to have tar change its operating directory as it processes arguments.

So this command:

```
tar -cf files.tar.gz -C folder1/folder2 file1 file2 -C ../folder3/folder4 file3 file4
```

will create `files.tar.gz` in the current directory with just the files in it.

You can automate creating the necessary command line arguments from `find` output or similar with a little bit of scripting if necessary.

(You can't use globs like `folder1/folder2/*` in the file argument positions because the paths in those filenames will cause `tar` to fail to find them. You can use `$(ls folder1/folder2/)` in that position but that's obviously not safe for many valid filenames.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is create hard links to /tmp, then archive from there, something like this :

```
mkdir /tmp/allfiles
find /home/user/folder1 -type f | while read file
do
ln $file /tmp/allfiles
done
cd /tmp/allfiles
tar cvf /tmp/myarchive.tar *
rm /tmp/allfiles/*
rmdir /tmp/allfiles
```

Note that hard link will only work if both /tmp and ~/folder1 are on the same filesystem. This will only make links and not consume extra diskspace.

You might remove the rm command at first. a type in your script could have bad results :-).

Comment: Note that if `/tmp` is on a separate file system, then you cannot create hard links across file systems, but symlinks wouldn't be correct either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without creating any temp dir :

```
find .type f  | pax -wv -s '/.*\///g' -f file.tar
```

from [`man pax`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pax) :

> pax — read and write file archives and copy directory hierarchies

Comment: Explanations of the flags/arguments and/or links to the documentation section for the flags would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have to create clumsy links or do without wildcards, you could could create your archive and then change directory and *append* to it (with the `r` option) like this:

```
tar cvf ~/archive.tar file*                             # make initial tarball
(cd folder2 && tar rvf ~/archive.tar file* )            # append others to it
(cd folder3/folder4 && tar -rvf ~/archive.tar file*)    # and more...
```

Note that I do the above in a subshell to avoid having to `cd` back afterwards.

Comment: Is this missing `-` on lines 1 & 2 before `cvf` and `rvf`?

Comment: @charles-allen I'm fairly sure they are optional.