# How can you archive with tar in NodeJS while only storing the subdirectory you want?

Tags: node.js, path, tar

Basically I want to do the equivalent of this [How to strip path while archiving with TAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043579/how-to-strip-path-while-archiving-with-tar) but with the tar commands imported to NodeJS, so currently I'm doing this:

```
const gzip = zlib.createGzip();
const pack = new tar.Pack(prefix="");
const source = Readable.from('public/images/');
const destination = fs.createWriteStream('public/archive.tar.gz');
pipeline(source, pack, gzip, destination, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', err);
        process.exitCode = 1;
    }
});
```

But doing so leaves me with files like: "/public/images/a.png" and "public/images/b.png", when what I want is files like "/a.png" and "/b.png". I want to know how I can add to this process to strip out the unneeded directories, while keeping the files where they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change working directory:

```js
// cwd The current working directory for creating the archive. Defaults to process.cwd().
new tar.Pack({ cwd: "./public/images" });
const source = Readable.from('');
```

Source: [documentation of `node-tar`](https://github.com/npm/node-tar#constructoroptions)

Example: https://github.com/npm/node-tar/blob/main/test/pack.js#L93

Comment: Using it as you have it written there gives me an error, "no such file or directory", and doing it like this "const pack = new tar.Pack({ cwd: "./public/images" });"
leaves the contents inside a directory with the name "." so...

Comment: Fixed it with this line "const source = Readable.from('');", but now there's an extra folder titled "."

Comment: It's close enough, please add those lines to your answer, so I can accept it.